# Anyone mind helping with this code?

Tags: bash, script

So basically what I want this script to do, is make a copy of a file every 300 seconds for example, but alternate between making a "savegame.backup1" file and then the next time 300 seconds pass "savegame.backup2" and then back to backup1.

My timer doesn't seem to repeat, and I'm unsure of how I can complete this script at all.

For context, a lot of the code I used was from googling, some was done by personal knowledge. I'm unable to find whatever it is I'm missing.

Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
GameType="Sandbox"  #Sandbox, Survival, etc.
SaveName="07-01-2017_04-52-11"  #Make sure you copy the folder name.
Timeout=$((5))  #Timeout in seconds. The default of 300 (5 minutes) is likely adequate.

#No need to change anything below.
GameName="Project Zomboid"
SERVICE=ProjectZomboid64 #Change this to ProjectZomboid32 if you're using 32bit java!
steam steam://rungameid/108600
# Checks to see if folder exists - if not, one will be made.
mkdir -p "$HOME/Zomboid/Saves/Backups/$SaveName"

#Loop start
while [ $Timeout -gt 0 ]; do
    clear && echo -ne "Creating a backup in" $Timeout "seconds."
    sleep 1
    : $((Timeout--))
    done
    clear
    if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
        then
            cp "$HOME/Zomboid/Saves/$GameType/$SaveName/map_p.bin" "$HOME/Zomboid/Saves/Backups/$SaveName/map_p.bin.backup1"
            #Need to alternate between the two each time it loops. Backup1 the first time, Backup2 the second, Backup1 the third...
            #cp "$HOME/Zomboid/Saves/$GameType/$SaveName/map_p.bin" "$HOME/Zomboid/Saves/Backups/$SaveName/map_p.bin.backup2"
            echo "$GameName is running. Backup made." #ERROR CHECKING
        else
            #Loop should end here, and prevent any further repeating of the loop.
            read -r -p "$GameName is not detected as running, and no further backups will be made."
        fi
    echo "Outside of loop." #ERROR CHECKING
    sleep 5s
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far to correct the problem(s), and what were the results?  First suggestion: you should recheck the syntax on how a While loop is constructed in Bash.

Comment: @TECHIE007 I tried to add another loop on the outside of the loop, and then another loop within the loop. So loop1 = infinite, loop2 inside of loop1 then loop3 inside of loop2. The answer given worked. Here's what I have now: http://pastebin.com/yk8k8Yxh but now all I need is to make $i add +1 each time it passes through, until it reaches the $BackupCount and resets itself to 1.

Comment: Oh and the results were mixed. The stuff I found to add to the code just didn't seem to work when I implemented them. I'm learning, though :D

Answer (score -1):

```
i=1
while :;do
if [ $(pgrep $SERVICE) ];then
    cp "$HOME/Zomboid/Saves/$GameType/$SaveName/map_p.bin" "$HOME/Zomboid/Saves/Backups/$SaveName/map_p.bin.backup$i"
    [ $i = 1 ] && i=2 || i=1
fi
sleep 300
done
```

Comment: Worked fine. Now I just need to figure out a way of making the script wait when it triggers the 'else' part so it can run through the loop again without the user having to press enter.